# В прилоение на angular & ionic5 для android и ios не удается получить разрешение на получение местополежения всегда

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic

Не только во время активного приложения. а и когда оно свернуто или заблокирован экран.

В приложеной картинке есть пример что нужно получить на основе 2gis. я использую Capacitor и это https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation. но когда я запускаю приложение у меня запрашивает разрешение и там нет выбора "Разрешить в любом ружиме", а только "Разрешить только во время использования приложения"(

[image: пример]

Comment: Вам сюда https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location Если кратко, то все зависит от версии android'а на устройстве и targetSDK вашего приложения. И сначала надо получить разрешение на геолокацию, потом запрашивать разрешение на фоновую геолокацию. А чтоб опубликовать такое приложение в маркете вам надо будет вывести информацию о том, для чего вам фоновая геолокация, иначе с апреля такие приложения будут заблокированы.

Comment: спасибо за наводку